# Как сделать заливку боксплота

Tags: r

Задача: Используйте данные с предыдущего шага и постройте боксплот смертности от злокачественной меланомы в зависимости от того, находится ли штат на побережье или нет. Используйте подходящую Брюйеровскую палитру для качественных (qualitative) данных. Добавьте подписи осей. График должен быть, как на приведенном рисунке, но можно использовать любую тему оформления, главное, чтобы была спрятана легенда. Сохраните график в переменную gg_box.
Рисунок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое решение:

> gg_box<-ggplot(data=USmelanoma, aes(x=ocean,
> y=mortality))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ocean))+scale_x_discrete(labels=c('нет',
> 'да'))+labs(x='океан', y='смертность на 1
> млн.чел.')+scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Dark2",
> direction = 1, aesthetics =
> "fill")+theme_grey()+theme(legend.position="none")

Описание проблемы:
В чем ошибка?

Comment: не вставляйте, пожалуйста, неработающие (и, соответственно, не относящиеся к сути вопроса) ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

заливку фигур цветом определяет параметр `fill` функции `aes()`. сравните:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill = factor(am))) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конкретные цвета можно указать с помощью семейства функций `scale_*_manual()` (параметр `values`). в случае определения цветов заливки (`fill`) нужна функция `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill = factor(am))) + geom_boxplot() \
  + scale_fill_manual(values = c('orange', 'pink'))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> gg_box<-ggplot(data=USmelanoma, aes(x=ocean,
>   y=mortality))+geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ocean))+scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Нет',
>   'Да'))+labs(x='Океан', y='Смертность на 1
>   млн.чел.')+scale_fill_brewer(palette =
>   "Dark2")+theme(legend.position="none")

Answer (score -1):

```
gg_box<-ggplot(data=USmelanoma, aes(x=ocean, y=mortality))+
        geom_boxplot(aes(fill=ocean))+
        scale_x_discrete(labels=c('Нет', 'Да'))+
        labs(x='Океан', y='Смертность на 1 млн. чел.')+
        scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
        theme_grey()+theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: хм. вы же просто скопировали [предыдущий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1036454/178576), не привнеся ничего нового (хотя бы пояснений, например).

Comment: 1. Ошибки с подписями осей x и y - надо с большой буквы, иначе не примет ответ 2. scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") достаточно только палитру указать - ответ принимается.